# Keras | Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**I can't run my neural network with categorical_crossentropy, but when I use binary I got not good accuracy. U know how to fix this?**

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: please add more information. You have 10 output neurons. Do you want classify 10 classes?

Comment: That's all code.

Comment: Yes, of course. I want classify 10 clasees. But was problem with output. Well, I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MNIST dataset has labels of shape (1,), while you output 10 values. If you want to use categorical crossentropy, you should use [SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) to resolve this difference as said in the [CategoricalCrossentropy documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) and the SparseCategoricalCrossentropy documentation.

Change your loss function:

```
from keras import losses
network.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank u again. And yeah, I can use sparse categorical cross-entropy too like this:
`loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',`